# Batch Script IF statement to DO something when size of all file types else DO different

Tags: shell, batch-file, if-statement

I need a batch script to do a command if files of a certain type over a certain size exist but the do another command to files of the same type the are under a certain size.
I then need the script to run another command if the first instance is true but the files contain something in the title.
Below is the current script however I do not want the 3 lines at the bottom to run when only 1 or 2 are required:

```
TASKKILL /IM "Plex Media Server.exe" /F
cd "C:\folder\Desktop"
robocopy "L:\folder1" *.mkv /mov /MAX:3200000000 /XF *keep*
robocopy "L:\folder2" *.mkv /mov /MIN:3200000000 /XF *.h-sbs.mkv *.h-ou.mkv *keep*
robocopy "L:\folder3" *.h-sbs.mkv *.h-ou.mkv /mov /MIN:3000000000
del *.sub *.idx *.html *.nfo *.sup *.txt *.htm
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Plex\Plex Media Server\Plex Media Server.exe"
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Plex\Plex Media Server"
"Plex Media Scanner.exe" --scan --refresh --section 1
"Plex Media Scanner.exe" --scan --refresh --section 2
"Plex Media Scanner.exe" --scan --refresh --section 3
netsh interface set interface name="LAN 2" admin=enabled
exit
```

Comment: Is that Alicia Silverstone?

Comment: Lol, close, do love her but no - Avril

Comment: Did my answer help? If you have questions, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started.

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    @echo File "%%~nI" is %%~zI bytes
    if %%~zI GTR 1000 echo This is larger than 1kb!
    if %%~zI LSS 1000 echo This is not 1kb :(
)
```

Comment: The answer I thought was correct below is still not working. It will not use the GOTO statements at the end of the IF statements. It checks the higher size and lower size and then just moves on in the script to the next line :(

Answer (score 1):

```
cd "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop"
:START
for %%I in (*.mkv) do (
  @echo File "%%~nI" is %%~zI bytes
  if %%~zI LSS 3200000000 GOTO TV
  if %%~zI GTR 3200000000 GOTO FILM
)
GOTO END
:TV
robocopy ".\" "L:\TV Shows 10" *.mkv /mov /MAX:3200000000 /XF *keep*
GOTO SCANTV
:FILM
robocopy ".\" "L:\HD Films 10" *.mkv /mov /MIN:3200000000 /XF *.h-sbs.mkv *.h-ou.mkv *keep*
robocopy ".\" "L:\3D HD Films 2" *.h-sbs.mkv *.h-ou.mkv /mov /MIN:3000000000
GOTO SCANFILM
:SCANTV
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Plex\Plex Media Server\Plex Media Scanner.exe" --scan --refresh --section 1
GOTO START
:SCANFILM
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Plex\Plex Media Server\Plex Media Scanner.exe" --scan --refresh --section 2
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Plex\Plex Media Server\Plex Media Scanner.exe" --scan --refresh --section 3
:END
del *.sub *.idx *.html *.nfo *.sup *.txt *.htm
exit
```

Thank you D.A. this helped to finally get to this but this was still the best I could do with it :-s